# how to start sidekiq automatically on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I have a Rails app which uses a Procfile to start sidekiq automatically on heroku. I'd like it to start sidekiq automatically on localhost (I currently just 'bundle exec sidekiq' in a separate window). Here's my procfile:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

How would I do this? I do have foreman installed locally

Comment: Just use `foreman start` in project root.

Comment: is there any way I can configure the app to run it on startup for dev?

Comment: You can use `foreman export` to upstart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990842/how-to-use-foreman-to-export-to-upstart.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Procfile.dev` file that's meant to be used in development. To use it, just do `'foreman start -f Procfile.dev'` from the terminal. Passing the `-f` option allows you to set the path the `Procfile` to use.

By the way, would probably be good to `gitignore` your Procfile.dev, as well. That way, others in your team could have their own `Procfile.dev`.

Hope that helps!